# ANTD: How to make input border with disable change color when error?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an Input component inside Form.item and input is disabled, I want input border to change color when error. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default disabled `border-color` by adding the following css to your app:

```css
.ant-input-status-error.ant-input-disabled,
.ant-input-status-error.ant-input-disabled:hover {
  border-color: #ff4d4f;
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-23-2-forked-l15hhp?file=/index.css) for a live working example of this solution.